# How can I use private variables in different ways

Tags: packages, contexts

How can I use some private variables/symbols in another sub contexts in different ways.

Note: Please do not use code Cell Style for testing the codes.

```
Begin["context1`"];

n = 5;

End[];

Begin["context2`"];

f[] := Print[n];

End[];
```

For example, here after evaluating `f[]`, we will not get `5`;

```
context2`f[]
```

context2`n

If we use variable `n` with context as following, then we get `5`;

```
Begin["context2`"];

f[] := Print[context1`n];

End[];

context2`f[]
```

5

My question is how can I not write `` context1` `` in `` Print[context1`n] ``, above, and get the result `5`.

Another approch is just for example

```
Begin["context2`"];

n = context1`n;

(*n2=context1`n;n1=context1`n1;

There are many variables, and I wrote them in a global context \

notebook file.

And now I want to migrate them into packages, with multiple contexts.

some thing like this step.

StringTrim[Names["context1`*"],"context1`"]=Names["context1"]

*)

f[] := Print[n];

h[] := Print[n];

End[];

context2`h[]
```

5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a matter of having the right `$ContextPath` at the time `n` is referenced. This is slightly complicated by the fact that contexts are interpreted at parse time, so typical tricks such as `Block` do not work. The behavior of `Begin` and `BeginPackage` are also different with respect to `$ContextPath`, but this is all discussed in the documentation, so I will let you examine that and decide which is the more suitable for your situation.

Regarding your question, it can be done simply by changing `$ContextPath` manually (but, with `Begin`, it is necessary to remember to put it back as it was to  start with, otherwise it could get hopelessly messed up and cause a lot of confusion). For example:

```
Begin["context1`"];

n = 5;

End[];

Begin["context2`"];
$ContextPath = Append[old$ContextPath = $ContextPath, "context1`"];

f[] := Print[n];

$ContextPath = old$ContextPath;
End[];

context2`f[] (* -> 5 *)
```

There may be other more elegant ways of approaching this depending on the real application and your specific requirements. But in any case, the key is in `$ContextPath`.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I think this answer solved my question, I've checked it in my package situation. `PrependTo[$ContextPath, "MyTest1`Private`"];`